# use Calendar/datepicker HTML <input type="date"> with a non-Gregorian locale, ‘fa-IR’

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, datetime-format, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Can the datepicker HTML :

```
<input type = "date">
```

be converted to a non-Gregorian locale, ‘fa-IR’(jalali or shamsi date picker)
by something like Intl.DateTimeFormat ??

Comment: I don't think fa-IR is supported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)